# Why .cuda() in forward doesn't work in my custom layer?

Tags: pytorch

The error occur in embedding line like above.

```
Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0!
```

The type of inputs[feature_name] are just list so I convert it to tensor using labelencoder then assigned cuda by .to() method. I also did model.to(device).

```
def forward(self, inputs):
    # other features
    encoded_other_features = []
    for i, feature_name in enumerate(OTHER_FEATURES):
      idx = self.other_features_encoder[i].batch_encode(inputs[feature_name])
      embedding = self.other_features_embedding[i](idx.to(device))
      print(embedding)
      encoded_other_features.append(embedding)
```

How can I run the model with cuda in this case?

Comment: What is `other_features_encoder` exactly? Can you provide the full error back trace?

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because there is a part that is not `.to('cuda')` .

1. Is it possible to allocate with `'cpu'`?
2. Or you need to check if you didn't do `.to('cuda')`.

What I doubt is,

Is `.to('cuda')` applied to `inputs`?

```
idx = self.other_features_encoder[i].batch_encode(inputs[feature_name])
```

try to change it to

```
idx = self.other_features_encoder[i].batch_encode(inputs[feature_name].to(device))
```